# Installed zsh via WSL. Git says he can't chdir to folder. What to do?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I used [this instruction](https://dev.to/vsalbuq/how-to-install-oh-my-zsh-on-windows-10-home-edition-49g2) to use zsh on my windows machine. Now it appears that git can't find my project folder, for some reason... what should I do here ?

https://ghostbin.co/paste/6sqz5

[image]

Comment: can you `cd /mnt/c/Users/Incognitus/Documents/Work/birthday-bot/` and try `git status` from there?

Comment: @jwalton doesn't work either. Same output.